# How to remove unneeded icons from the menu?

Tags: launcher, app-drawer

I have a Samsung i9220 with Android 4.1.1. How can I remove the unneeded icons from the android phones menu?

[image]

Comment: What you're showing there in your screen shot is called the "App Drawer". It lists all the apps that are installed on the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By menu, I'm assuming you are referring to the app drawer. I don't know if the stock Samsung launcher gives you the ability to hide apps, but several 3rd party launchers offer that functionality. [Apex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher&hl=en) and [Nova](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en) both give you the ability to hide and create custom app groups in the drawer. There are free versions of both in the market with each offering a paid version with expanded functionality.